# Iterating through a pandas dataframe to create a chart that adds up to 100%

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

[image: Existing Dataframe]

I want add two columns "Stat total during quarter"(total value of "stat" without break down by param applied) and "% of quarter total" -- that would show how proportions have been changing over time and build a stacked chart that adds up to 100%

[image]

Unfortunately I have troubles calculating "Stat total during quarter" in the "pandas way".
I ended up iterating through the dataframe cell-by-cell which feels like a suboptimal solution and then dividing one column by another to get the %

```
for elements in df.index:
 df.ix[elements,3] = df[df['period']==df.ix[elements,0]]['stat'].sum()
df['% of quarter total'] = df.stat / df.['stat total during quarter']
```

Would really appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby/transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to compute the sum for each period. `transform` always returns a Series of the same length as the original DataFrame. Thus, you can assign the return value to a new column of `df`:

```
df['stat total during quarter'] = df.groupby('period')['stat'].transform('sum')
df['% of quarter total'] = df['stat'] / df['stat total during quarter']
```